# i keep coming back to login page in php

Tags: php, windows

newbie here...
so yeah, i already tried searching all those page-related about my question, but im still stuck...
anyway, my problem is that i always keep getting back at my login page, which is my index.php
oh btw, im still using PHP version 4.4.8
here is my code for my problematic main page, main.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
include '../config.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
 header("location:index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>KSP Setia Finance</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>test page</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here is my login page code, which is index.php

```html
<?php 
session_start();
include '../config.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <title>Login Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login">
 <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="login_act.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <button type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Log In</button>
    </form>
</div>
  
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

since everyone asking, here my login_act.php, already inserted with session_start

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('../config.php');
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 $user = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['username']));
 $pass = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(md5($_POST['password'])));
 
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
  echo 'User not found';
 }else{
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
  if($row['level'] == 1){
   $_SESSION['admin']=$user;
   echo '<script language="javascript">alert("u are Login as Admin!"); document.location="index.php";</script>';
  }else
   echo 'sorry, u cant access this one';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: please post also the login_act.php code

Comment: Hi. [PHP 4 is not maintained anymore](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), you should try upgrade your version too.

Answer (score 0):

print value of $_SESSION on main.php and check if there is any key as 'username' and check login.php, what values are you storing in $_SESSION array

Answer (score 0):

so i recently asking my friends, and here is the results:
all i need is just put those $SESSION_START above all, or make another php and link them all. so here my latest result that worked :
main.php

```html
<?php
include 'access.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>KSP Setia Finance</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>test page</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

access.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
 
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
 echo '<script language="javascript">alert("you must Login!"); document.location="../index.php";</script>';
}
?>
```

and last, config.php

```html
<?php
session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("koperasi");
?>
```

i deleted that broken login_act.php, and making all the page i had to be linked directly with the access.php, which make it easier to manage the session. thank you to all that bear with my php problem and stupidity. hope this all gonna help those who still wandering and asking the same question.